# Transexponential Functions

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, logic, model-theory

Recall that $\exp(1,x) = e^x$ and $\exp(n+1,x) = e^{\exp(n,x)}$.

Recall that $f(x)$ is transexponential if $f(x)$ is eventually greater than $\exp(n,x)$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$

I am looking for a (general) reference on these types of functions (or any paper about these functions, or maybe even a few pages of a textbook).

**Note:** I have tagged model theory (and now logic) since the only context in which I have encountered transexponential functions is in relation to Wilkie's Conjecture (and so model theorists know about these functions). Please note that I am looking for a reference about transexponential function in general, and **not** a link to an exposition of Wilkie's Conjecture.

**Note 2:** I have added a bounty to this question. I am trying to get my hands dirty with transexponential functions from $\mathbb{R}^+ \to \mathbb{R}^+$. The most helpful answer would be one where I could "in some sense" compute the derivative (locally). Please do not answer with "piecewise continuous segments" + bump functions.

Comment: Try looking up "tower functions" or "Ackerman functions".

Comment: Not entirely sure if this is what you're looking for, but: you may find transseries interesting (see http://www.math.ucla.edu/~matthias/pdf/oleron.pdf). Basically, this is a model-theoretically natural class of objects, which stretch well into the transexponential (for instance, they include (series corresponding to) functions like $e^{e^x}$).

Comment: I have taken the freedom to correct a small error (I think) in the first line  of your post. Please roll back or contact me if you do not agree with my edits.

Comment: @NoahSchweber: I have read some of the literature on transseries and was under the impression that for the most part they diverge everywhere? I could be completely wrong about that. Anyway, I would be delighted with a specific example of an element of a transseries which fits the description above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to obtain transexponential functions while having some control on their growth is through the *Abel equation* for the exponential function. This is the following equation in $E$:

$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $ $\forall r\gg1,E(r+1)=\exp(E(r))$  $\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $**(A)**

(where $\forall r\gg 1$ means: for sufficiently large $r \in \mathbb{R}$).

Any solution $E:(a,+\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to **(A)** which is continuous is transexponential. Indeed, fix $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and write $m:= \min E([a+1,a+2))=E(b)$. The function $k \mapsto \exp(k,m)$ eventually dominates $k \mapsto \exp(n,b+k+1)$, say starting from $k_0 \in \mathbb{N}$. For $r >b+ k_0$, we have $E(r)\geq E(b+\left\lfloor r-b\right\rfloor)=\exp(\left\lfloor r-b\right\rfloor,m)>\exp(n,b+\left\lfloor r-b\right\rfloor+1)>\exp(n,r)$.

Hellmuth Kneser first came up with quasi-analytic solutions to this equation and derived some bounds on the derivative. If you can read German, see [his article](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN243919689_0187?tify=%7B%22pages%22:[62],%22panX%22:0.414,%22panY%22:0.789,%22view%22:%22info%22,%22zoom%22:0.359%7D).
You can find complements on this topic in the Appendix A of [this Phd thesis](https://www.texmacs.org/joris/schmeling/schmeling.pdf) (only the introduction is in French, and it is translated into English in Appendix B).